# Why is my filter function not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

simple react component that should be filtering a list. not working and i have no idea why...

```
import React from 'react';

class Filter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: '',
    items: [{name: 'lol'}]
  }

  handleChange = (event) => this.setState({ input: event.target.value })

  render(){
    const { input, items } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="search for an item"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {items.filter(term => term.includes(input)).map((term) => (
          <div>{term.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Filter;
```

literally filtering the array, then mapping over it....

Comment: You should add more details, "not working" is not really helpful. But I guess that it should be `term.name.includes(input)` instead.

Comment: ah yes thats it. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

class Filter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: '',
    items: [{name: 'lol'}],
    filteredItems: false,
  } 

   filter(e) {
          var value = e.target.value;
          this.setState({filterval: value})

          this.setState({
            filteredItems: !value
              ? false
              : this.state.items.filter(function (item) {
                return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
              })
          })
        }


    render(){



            var list = this.state.filteredItems || this.state.items || []

            return (
             <div>
         <input placeholder="search for an item" onChange={this.filter.bind(this)}
        />
<div>

              {list.map((item,index) => (


                           <div>{term.name}</div>
                        ))}
</div>    
 </div>
 )
```

Comment: You should add a description of what you changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
items.filter(term => term.includes(input))
```

The condition here is not correct. The variable `term` is an object `{name: 'lol'}`. The `includes` is not available for an object.
It's should be `term.name.includes(input)` or `term.name === input`